# My Windows 10 PC isn't picking up any sound coming from my BM-800 Mic wired through my pre-amplifier

Tags: microphone, preamp

I bought a BM-800 Condenser Microphone

[image]

The Mic has a 3.5mm jack so I'm using an adaptor (3.5mm female to 6.5mm male)

[image]

I have it hooked up into the Mono 6.6mm jack of a Joseph MIX-278 Phono/Mic Pre-Amplifier which uses a 12v power supply.

[image]

Still with everything connected correctly, My Windows 10 PC doesn't pic up any sound coming from the mic. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: See the linked question, but in short, I'd replace that existing mic preamp which has no phantom power, with a USB mic pre which does (& a proper XLR>XLR mic cable). You'll also gain cleaner inputs over USB to your computer than using its regular audio inputs.